# Why does an App die during a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I commonly need to perform migrations like so:

```
class AddNewFieldToMember < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :members, :new_field, :string, :default => 'instant'

    # Set existing records
    Member.reset_column_information
    Member.all.each do |member|
      member.new_field = 'instant'
      member.save
    end

  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :members, :new_field
  end
end
```

This specific Member table has about 10,000 records. When we run migrations like this one everything dies. The migration takes at least 5 minutes. Rails is not responsive, the postgresql is also not responsive.

Why is that? What can be done to avoid this kind of migration downtime? Is there a better way to add migrations and update existing records?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new column with a default value, you do not need to loop existing records to add it. The database engine should take care of that.

PostgreSQL could be hanging if the migration is within a transaction and the data being modified is also modified somewhere else during the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

@MartinSamson is right, default should handle this situation.  And if for some reason you needed to do some other sort of update to the values that default cannot handle, it is way more efficient to do it in sql.  E.g.

```
execute("update members set new_field='value'")
```

rather than executing through all of the entities this way.

Oh, and another thing, I strongly recommend NEVER referencing your objects in your migrations, it just leads to problems.  For example, what if, at a later date, you delete the `Member` class from your application.  Then your migrations fail the next time you run them from scratch, which is annoying.  Much better to just do it in SQL.

Comment: No, the SQL will NOT fail...migrations are run in the same order, so the state of the db is known when you run the migration.  If you were to drop the members table, it would be done in another migration that is run AFTER this one.  However, the models of the application (e.g. whether the member.rb class exists is NOT known when you run the migration.  If you have deleted the member class, it no longer exists thus the migration will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's right that you may not even need to do that, but if you want to set the value explicitly, or need to do this otherwise...

If you have 10,000 members, then you're issuing 10,000 update statements with implicit transactions.

Check out [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid accessing models inside your migrations, unless it's really unavoidable.

Your specific case can be solved with:

```
class AddNewFieldToMember < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :members, :new_field, :string, :default => 'instant'

    # Set existing records
    execute <<-SQL
      update members set new_field = 'instant';
    SQL
  end
```

If, by any means, you really need to use your model inside the migration, at least use the most efficient method `find_each` instead of `all.each`. Wrapping the loop inside a transaction might get you better results as well.